# What is this typescript type `[_user: 'some one']`? How can I retrieve the key '_user' in this?

Tags: arrays, typescript, key

When I get a log by using ethers.js, after I parsed the log, I got a variable args, if I console.log(args) it, it prints like below:

```
[
  '1111',
  '2222',
  _name: '1111',
  _user: '2222'
]
```

When I try to encode it to json:

```
JSON.stringify(args);
```

It becomes:

```
['1111','2222']
```

So what is type this parsed args?  Is there a way to retrieve the key we see above, like the '_name'?

Thanks!

Comment: `[ '1111',  '2222',  _name: '1111',  _user: '2222' ]` is not valid runtime code: an array can't have `_name:` or `_user` in it.  It *might* be a type annotation for a tuple with labelled values but it's also unusual. Is it just an array you've logged which has random properties added to it? Then yes, serialising it only treats it as an array. But overall, it's hard to figure out what you actually have and also what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've trying to save the logs from ethers locally.  Something like [{"_name":"1111","_user": "2222"}].  I want to save the values with their keys.  I'm not familiar with js/ts.  Don't know how they implemented the log response.

Comment: What is the intent? Do you want to model the type of this variable or do you want to produce sth more regular from the parser?